# Add widget in socialengine plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I want custom group plugin by Social engine
So in `application/modules/Group/settings/content.php` I added :

```
  array(
      'title' => 'Overall Statistic',
      'description' => 'Displays overall statistic of groups on group home page.',
      'category' => 'Groups',
      'type' => 'widget',
      'name' => 'group.overall-statistic',
      'defaultParams' => array(
          'title' => 'Overall Statistic',
      ),
  ),
```

In widget folder in group plugin I added two files : Controller.php and Index.php
(it looks like this : `application/modules/Group/widgets/overall-statistic`)

controller.php :

```
<?php

class Group_Widget_OverallStatisticController extends Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $groupTable = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('group');


    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($groupTable->getAdapter());
    $select -> from($groupTable->info('name'), 'COUNT(*) AS count')
            -> where('group_id > 0');
    $this->view->count_groups =  $select->query()->fetchColumn(0);


    $albumTable = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('advgroup_album');
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($albumTable->getAdapter());
    $select->from($albumTable->info('name'), 'COUNT(*) AS count')
            -> where('album_id > 0');;
    $this->view->count_albums =  $select->query()->fetchColumn(0);


    $photoTable = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('advgroup_photo');
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($photoTable->getAdapter());
    $select->from($photoTable->info('name'), 'COUNT(*) AS count')
            -> where('photo_id > 0');;
    $this->view->count_photos =  $select->query()->fetchColumn(0);

    $topicTable = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('advgroup_topic');
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($topicTable->getAdapter());
    $select->from($topicTable->info('name'), 'COUNT(*) AS count')
           ->where('topic_id > 0');;
    $this->view->count_topics =  $select->query()->fetchColumn(0);
  }
}
```

index.php :

```
<ul class = "global_form_box" style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding : 0px 15px 15px 15px;">
        <br/>
      <div class="statistic_info"> <?php echo $this->translate('Total Groups');?></div>
      <div class="statistic_count">  <?php echo $this->count_groups?> </div>
       <br/>
      <div class="statistic_info"> <?php echo $this->translate('Total Albums');?></div>
      <div class="statistic_count">  <?php echo $this->count_albums?> </div>
        <br/>
      <div class="statistic_info"> <?php echo $this->translate('Total Photos');?></div>
      <div class="statistic_count">  <?php echo $this->count_photos?> </div>
        <br/>
      <div class="statistic_info"> <?php echo $this->translate('Total Topics'); ?></div>
      <div class="statistic_count">  <?php echo $this->count_topics?> </div>
 </ul>
```

In panel admin I added the widget when I want show it but index.php doesn't appear in my website ..

Controller.php work well because when I add (in controller.php)

```
var_dump($groupTable); die;
```

I can see it in my website

How is it possible? Is what I forgot to edit a file?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create index.tpl instead of index.php

Better to create this widget out of core plugin to avoid future upgrades.